# how to create a form that adds an entry to a database and email a link to that entry

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, email

I am creating a feedback form (email & feedback text fields),which adds an entry to a Feedback Table. An auto-incremented FeedbackID is generated once the form is submitted and entry is added to the DB. Upon submission of the form, an email is also sent to the email. How do i add a link in the email pointing to that specific feedback.(ex: http://localhost/site/feedback.php?id= ) Feedback ID is only generated in the DB once entry is added to the database.

Comment: Attach your progress. How much you have done.

Comment: Show us what you've done and where you're stuck.

Comment: Do you need just retrieve the feedbackID from the table?

Comment: I havent started yet. I'm still planning on how it flows. After submitting the form, it adds an entry to the DB. How do I retrieve that entry without knowing its FeedbackID? Yes, I need to include the FeedbackID in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database will generate an ID on entering, and you can extract that ID in code, then insert it into your email; so assuming you are using mysqli:

```
$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id
```

[mysqli insert id documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

or PDO:

```
$lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

[PDO last insert id documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

or codeigniter (just saw you had tagged this)

```
$lastId = $this->db->insert_id();
```

[CI Database helpers documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)